# Cocoa get first day in week

Tags: ios, nsdate, nscalendar

How to get the first day of a week for a date

this seems more easy at it is, since :

- when the week starts with sunday, i need to get back the sunday date
- if it starts on monday, i need to get the monday date

the input date is any date in week with time... i tried several approaches, but the edge case make it difficould

i made a function, which however doesn't work in 100% (not sure about the [components setDay: -weekday + 2];)

```
- (NSDate *)firstDateOfWeek {

    NSCalendar * calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents = [calendar components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) fromDate:self];
    // because sunday is 0, we need it to be 6
    NSInteger weekday = (([weekdayComponents weekday] + 6) % 7);

    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) fromDate:self];
    [components setDay: -weekday + 2];

    return [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is easier to use the `rangeOfUnit` calendar method, which handles "start of the week" correctly according to the current locale:

```
NSDate *date = your date;
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *startOfWeek;
[calendar rangeOfUnit:NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit
            startDate:&startOfWeek
             interval:NULL
              forDate:date];
```

Using `NSDateComponents`, it would work as follows (assuming that a week has 7 days):

```
NSDate *date = your date;
NSDateComponents *comp = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSWeekdayCalendarUnit
                                     fromDate:date];
NSDate *startOfDay = [calendar dateFromComponents:comp];
NSInteger diff = (NSInteger)[calendar firstWeekday] - (NSInteger)[comp weekday];
if (diff > 0)
    diff -= 7;
NSDateComponents *subtract = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[subtract setDay:diff];
NSDate *startOfWeek = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:subtract toDate:startOfDay options:0];
```

Comment: what would be the equivalent of this using date components?

Comment: also NSWeekCalendarUnit is deprecated :/

Comment: but wouldn't the NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit make problems at the beginning of year? giving back 1.1. instead of the real first day in week

Comment: @PeterLapisu: I just tested it with "2013-01-03" and the result was "2012-12-31" (the week starts on a Monday in Germany).

Comment: @PeterLapisu: Just for the sake of completeness (or just for fun :-) I have added the equivalent code using date components.

Comment: @SilviuSt: I am pretty sure that it works. But note that NSLog'ing a NSDate always uses GMT, so if it is Sunday (midnight) at your location, it might still be Saturday in London/Greenwich.

Comment: On simulator returns Saturday, on my iPhone returns 2015-07-26 21:00:00 (hour shouldn't have been 00:00 and date 27(monday))? How can i see real date, with gmt +2 attached? I am from Romania ( gmt +2 )

Comment: @SilviuSt: You have summer time in Romania, so the difference to GMT is three hours. "2015-07-26 21:00:00 GMT" time is exactly "2015-07-27 00:00:00" in your timezone. To "see" the date according to your timezone, use a NSDateFormatter and convert the NSDate to a string.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @MartinR I have missed that.

Comment: @MartinR i recieve previous date as first weekof day  using rangeOfUnit function , so i set setFirstWeekday:2 to have to the exact date , is it the correct way of doing it

Comment: @Mr.G: Sorry, I do not understand your question.

Comment: @MartinR i used ur first code sample . it gave a day ahead which means to saturday   , so i set     [calendar setFirstWeekday:2]; this gave me the exact date which is sunday , so i need to know whether this is the correct way of doing it ?