# Region Format Not Working Correctly in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

For the phone settings, I realised when my users was with United Kingdom's Region Format, it turns the week range into 10th November 2013 - 16th November 2013. But for United States, it shows the correct week range which is 03th November 2013 - 09th November 2013.

Is there anyone know the correct way to solve programatically?

Here are my piece of codes...

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *currentWeekFirstDay = [CWHelperTime getFirstDayOfWeek:[NSDate date]];

if( !self.weekStartDate ){

    self.weekStartDate = currentWeekFirstDay;

} else {

    NSDateComponents *prevWeekStartComponents = [gregorian components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:self.weekStartDate];

    if( self.currentWeekIndex < weekIndex )
        prevWeekStartComponents.day = +7;
    else
        prevWeekStartComponents.day = -7;

    self.currentWeekIndex = weekIndex;        
    self.weekStartDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:prevWeekStartComponents toDate:self.weekStartDate options:0];
}

NSDateComponents *weekEndComponents = [gregorian components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:self.weekStartDate];
weekEndComponents.day = +6;
self.weekEndDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:weekEndComponents toDate:self.weekStartDate options:0];
```

This is for the getFirstDayOfWeek

```
[NSTimeZone setDefaultTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Asia/Singapore"]];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSWeekCalendarUnit|NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];

// Find Sunday for the given date
components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSWeekCalendarUnit|NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
[components setWeekday:1]; // 1 == Sunday, 7 == Saturday
[components setWeek:[components week]];

return [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
```

Comment: What is CWHelperTime?

Comment: Oops, sorry it's my own written function to get the first day of the week. And I just edited it. @MartinR

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/16876859/1187415 for a simpler method to get the first day of the week, that should work correctly. Note also that in some regions Sunday is the first day of the week, and in other regions it is Monday.