# Finding the locale-dependent first day of the week

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

Given an `NSDate`, how do I find the first day of that date's week, given the user's locale. For example, I've heard that some countries treat Monday as the first day of the week and others use Sunday. I need to return the preceding Monday in the first case but the preceding Sunday in the latter case.

My best effort thus far always returns the preceding Sunday, regardless of the device settings applied:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
[calendar setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearForWeekOfYearCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:originalDate];
[components setWeekday:1];
NSDate *firstDayOfWeek = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
```

Bonus question: on iOS, which setting drives this? Is it the 'Region Format'?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876813/cocoa-get-first-day-in-week?rq=1 which solves the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing:

```
[components setWeekday:1];
```

to:

```
[components setWeekday:[calendar firstWeekday]];
```

You should also remove the `NSYearForWeekOfYearCalendarUnit` and `NSWeekCalendarUnit` components.

Bonus Question: "Region Format" should be the setting that changes the first day of the week.

Comment: Thanks - I read that NSYearForWeekOfYearCalendarUnit and NSWeekCalendarUnit are necessary to handle a date like Wednesday, January 2nd, where the preceding first weekday is in the previous year. I will see if I can find the source.

Comment: @BenPackard I'll admit I suggested removing them because those don't seem necessary. I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

An smarter way for old style for those who do not want to set calendar firstWeekday.

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1483620311.228]; 
NSLog(@"current date ===> : %@", date);
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDate *previousMonday = [calendar nextDateAfterDate:date 
                                    matchingUnit:NSCalendarUnitWeekday  
                                           value:2 //use 1-7 for Sunday to Saturday week day.
                                         options:NSCalendarMatchNextTime | NSCalendarSearchBackwards];
NSLog(@"previousMonday date ===> : %@", previousMonday);
```