# Force Calendar to use NSLocale first week day

Tags: objective-c, date, calendar

In iOS simulator I need to force the first weekday dependent upon the current locale.

I've tried this several times, but each time it reports that the first week day is 1 (sunday).

In the simulator I try setting to Germany, check the iOS calendar and see its a Monday; then I go to my app and relaunch this view -- it should also say Monday; but it still reports Sunday and the first week day being 1, when it should be 2.

How do I fix this so that it always forces to be the correct first week day for that given locale?

I tried this solution: [Finding the locale-dependent first day of the week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668942/finding-the-locale-dependent-first-day-of-the-week)  but it doesn't seem to work for me.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
[calendar setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[calendar setFirstWeekday:[calendar firstWeekday]]; // Sunday == 1, Saturday == 7

[calendar setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearForWeekOfYearCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
[components setWeekday:[calendar firstWeekday]];
NSDate *firstDayOfWeek = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[f setDateFormat:@"EEE"];

NSString *formatted = [f stringFromDate:firstDayOfWeek];
NSLog(@"Formatted = %@", formatted);
```

The above always reports Sunday.

This is for locales: `en` (germany) and united states (`en_US`)

Is there a way to force the first work day to be reliant upon the locale without me hardcoding it?

Thanks

Comment: Log the locale and verify it is `*_DE` (the language won't matter but the country does).

Comment: BTW - there is a much easier way to do what you want. Create an `NSDateFormatter`. Then do: `NSString *weekdayString = [formatter shortWeekdaySymbols][[NSCalendar currentCalendar] firstWeekday - 1];`. That's it. Two lines of code.

Comment: I will try it, as I need to verify in other countries too.

Comment: Keep in mind that the locale's country will determine the first day of the week while the locale's language will determine that actual string returned for the given weekday name.

Comment: Not sure about this because if I do firstWeekday-1 on a Sunday, then the first day is a Saturday which is not true for `en_US`.

Comment: `firstWeekday - 1` is to get proper array access. Sunday = 1 but arrays start at 0. In other words, `firstWeekday` has values in the range 1 - 7 but the `shortWeekdaySymbols` needs an index in the range 0 - 6.

Comment: Ah, okay. I was just using the `[f setDateFormat:@"EEE"];` as a easy way to output the day it was returning.

Comment: This still doesn't really make sense. If I'm in Germany, the `calendar.firstWeekday` is 1 which is `Monday`, I've verifed this in the logs.  But if I then subtract firstWeekday from the calender, its `Sunday`.   If I subtract 1 from the shortWeekdaySymbols; its `Sunday`.   I think I will play with the idea where I can use the `firstWeekday` against the display of the calendar

Comment: It makes perfect sense. In Germany, the first day of the week is Monday, right? This means that `NSCalendar firstWeekday` will return `2` (not `1`) to represent Monday. The value of `NSCalendar firstWeekday` is from 1-7. But the `NSDateFormatter shortWeekdaySymbols` is a 0-based array. So you must subtract `1` from `firstWeekday` to access the desired symbol.